# how to add the unified response body to ApiResponse

Tags: android-architecture-components

I want add unified response by modifying **ApiResource**. It is a **HTTP body**, it always contains json data below:

```
{
  data: T
  message: String
  status: Int
}
```

I tried to add

```
val gson = Gson()
val stewardResponse = gson.fromJson(
    response.body().toString(),
    StewardResponse::class.java
)

if (body == null || response.code() == 204) {
    ApiEmptyResponse()
} else {
    ApiSuccessResponse(
        body = stewardResponse.data,
        linkHeader = response.headers()?.get("link")
    )
 }
```

but failed with the tip:

> **Type mismatch**.
>
> **Required:** ApiResponse<T> **Found:** ApiSuccessResponse<Any?>

Comment: val gson = Gson()
                val stewardResponse = gson.fromJson(response.body().toString(), StewardResponse::class.java)
                
                if (body == null || response.code() == 204) {
                    ApiEmptyResponse()
                } else {
                    ApiSuccessResponse(
                        body =stewardResponse.data,
                        linkHeader = response.headers()?.get("link")
                    )
                }

Comment: It is from the GithubBrowserSample

Comment: it is useful for that api that not include status in the body, but for the api include business logic in body, did someone have a solution?

Comment: I will take a look at this now. Can you describe your development stack?

Comment: @HassanVoyeau the demo is written in kotlin

Comment: What type is stewardResponse.data? Can you show the code that defines the class StewardResponse?

Comment: data class StewardResponse{
  data: T,
  message: String,
  status: Int,
}

Comment: @HassanVoyeau data class StewardResponse{ data: T, message: String, status: Int}

Comment: Can you add your ApiSuccessResponse constructor code?

Comment: @HassanVoyeau Let me make it Clear，In Google's demo GithubBrowserSample,Which use the http status to indicate whether the response data is correct or not.But what puzzled me is that, existed Api provide to me is like this {
  data: T
  message: String
  status: Int
}.When the status equals 0, the data contains the data used for the UI.When the status is not equals 0,It only response status and message.Because I am new to kotlin, I am wondering how to solve this .